# Django - non-consecutive months

Tags: django, django-custom-tags

I would like to produce a list on the side of my blog that shows the year and the months that have entries only, like this:

```
2011 - Jan, Feb
2010 - Jan, Mar, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Oct, Nov, Dec
2009 - Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
```

I have made custom template tag so that I can place it into the base.html.

Currently it produces a list that looks like this:

```
2011 - 1, 2
2010 - 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12
2009 - 9, 10, 11, 12
```

I have built a custom template tag that is(thanks to [Alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/alasdair) and [cig212](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199170/cig212)):

```
from django import template
from blog.models import Post

register = template.Library()

class PostList(template.Node):
def __init__(self, var_name):
    self.var_name = var_name

def render(self, context):
    my_months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
       'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

       arch = Post.objects.dates('publish', 'month', order='DESC')

       archives = {}
       for i in arch:
         year = i.year
         month = i.month
         if year not in archives: 
             archives[year] = [] 
             archives[year].append(month) 
         else: 
             if month not in archives[year]: 
                 archives[year].append(month)

    context[self.var_name] = archives.items()
    return ''


@register.tag
def get_post_list(parser, token):
    """
    Generates a list of months that blog posts exist.
    Much like the 'year' archive.

    Syntax::

      {% get_post_list as [var_name] %}

    Example usage::

      {% get_post_list as posts_list %}
      (This 'var_name' is the one inserted into the Node)

    """
    try:
       tag_name, arg = token.contents.split(None, 1)
    except ValueError:
       raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, "%s tag requires arguments" % token.contents.split()[0]
    m = re.search(r'as (\w+)', arg)
    if not m:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, "%s tag had invalid arguments" % tag_name
    var_name = m.groups()[0]
    return PostListNode(var_name)
```

The template looks like so:

```
{% load blog %}
{% get_post_list as posts_list %}
{% for years, months in posts_list %} 
    {{ years }} 
    {% for month in months %} 
    <a href="{{ years }}/{{ month }}">{{ month }}</a> 
    {% endfor %} 
    <br /> 
{% endfor %}
```

So how can I get my `my_months` labels that are in the custom tag on to the month numbers produced by the tag. I know that I need to use `enumerate()` in the custom tag but I am getting lost somewhere.

Comment: I have made the question clearer, I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 if year not in archives: 
     archives[year] = [] 
     archives[year].append(month) 
 else: 
     if month not in archives[year]: 
         archives[year].append(month)
```

to

```
 if year not in archives: 
     archives[year] = {} 
     archives[year][month] = my_months[month - 1]
 else: 
     if month not in archives[year]: 
         archives[year][month] = my_months[month - 1]
```

and then

```
{% for years, months in posts_list %} 
    {{ years }} 
    {% for month in months %} 
    <a href="{{ years }}/{{ month }}">{{ month }}</a> 
    {% endfor %} 
    <br /> 
{% endfor %}
```

to

```
{% for years, months in posts_list %} 
    {{ years }} 
    {% for month_number, month_name in months.items %} 
    <a href="{{ years }}/{{ month_number }}">{{ month_name }}</a> 
    {% endfor %} 
    <br /> 
{% endfor %}
```

This should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Hey heey Aidas, thanks a lot. I need to read up more on Python lists. Your answer was it.

Here is the code I finally used.
For the custom tag:

```
class PostList(template.Node):
def __init__(self, var_name):
    self.var_name = var_name

def render(self, context):
    my_months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
       'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

    arch = Post.objects.dates('publish', 'month', order='DESC')

    archives = {}
    for i in arch:
        year = i.year
        month = i.month
        if year not in archives: 
            archives[year] = {} 
            archives[year][month] = my_months[month - 1]
        else: 
            if month not in archives[year]: 
                archives[year][month] = my_months[month - 1]

    context[self.var_name] = sorted(archives.items(),reverse=True)
    return ''
```

Note the reversing of the items in the list.

For the template:

```
{% get_post_list as posts_list %}
{% for years, months in posts_list %} 
     {{ years }} 
     {% for month_number, month_name in months.items %} 
          <li>
             <a href="{{ years }}/{{ month_name|lower }}/">{{ month_name }}</a> 
          </li>
      {% endfor %} 
      <br /> 
{% endfor %}
```

And the output has both years and months reversed. Perfect!